# Worst case complexity of creating a HashSet<int> from a collection

Tags: c#, .net, complexity-theory

I have a collection of `int` values with which I populate a `HashSet<int>` in the following manner -

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(myIEnumerable);
```

Assuming that iterating the `IEnumerable` is `O(n)`, what will be the **worst case** complexity of creating a `HashSet<int>` in such a way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation actually states:

> This constructor is an O(n) operation, where n is the number of
>   elements in the collection parameter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504.aspx

Comment: But is it worst-case complexity or amortized complexity?

Comment: @UghSegment You mean "average" complexity not "amortized". "Amortized" is used for operations which are sometimes expensive (for example a doubling of the backing store) and cheap for the rest. That concept is orthogonal to average vs. worstcase.

Comment: @UghSegment To add to CodeInChaos' answer, it is both the worst case and the amortized complexity.  (Given that he explained why it's possible for it to be both, I'm stating that's actually the case here.)

Comment: @Servy I understand that both can be the same; but that doesn't really affect my question - Is the *worst case* complexity `O(n)`?

Comment: No, in general worst case is quadratic of course, but this is for objects with the same GetHashCode() output. I'm wondering about int's.

Comment: @UghSegment What do you think is the worst case. The algorithm checks the first element of `myIEnumerable`, checks if it's already in the dictionary (that's in constant time), and if not, adds it. Then checks the second element of `myIEnumerable`, see if it's already in the dictionary, and otherwise adds it. What do you think is the worst case? Maybe that all the elements are distinct but the hash codes collides every time? Try making a class that overrides `GetHashCode()` to always return 0, and overrides `Equals(object)` to return `ReferenceEquals`. Then measure for yourself!

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen My question is specifically about the worst case complexity of `HashSet<int>`, not HashSets in general.

Comment: @UghSegment As people have written elsewhere on this page, for an `int`, the `GetHashCode()` method simply returns `this`. For example `(-987654321).GetHashCode() == -987654321`. Therefore, you _never_ get collisions with `int`. According to the documentation, the constructor overload you use sets `capacity` to the needed size immediately, so maybe the `HashSet<>` won't have to resize itself. In that case, I would suspect the worst-case complexity is O(n).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That is what I thought. However, I believe that despite having no hash collisions it is still possible to produce collisions with the element index in the buckets - and this is what makes me think that this operation might be higher than `O(n)` in certain situations. I might be wrong though, since I don't know very well how `HashSet` is implemented in .NET.

Comment: Of course different ints can collide. If there are 7 buckets then the ints `n` and `n+7` collide. => This answer does not address worst-case performance.

Comment: @UghSegment Try debugging and inspecting the `private` fields of the `HashSet<>` with the debugger. You will probably see what "buckets" or modulus is chosen. Maybe for a given size of your input collection, you can figure out what buckets are used. Then make your collection of the same size, but choose the members in an evil way. That should be possible. So maybe it's worse than O(n) after all, for "evil" input.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I used .NET Reflector to find out how the `HashSet` gets the modulus value it uses in the hashing calculation. I used this information to provide the constructor with various values that all fall into the same index and the performance degradation in my tests seemed to be almost perfectly quadratic. It seems after all that the worst case complexity is indeed `O(n^2)`, even without collisions in the hash values.

Comment: @UghSegment Really cool. CodesInChaos anticipated that in his comment to one of the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

You can bring the worst case to `O(N^2)` by supplying objects that all hash to the same bucket *when the set reaches its maximum size*. For example, if you pass a sequence of 17519 `int`s constructed as

```
x[i] = i * 17519
```

for `i` between 1 and 17519, inclusive, all numbers will hash to the initial bucket on Microsoft's implementation of `HashSet<int>`, taking `O(N^2)` to insert:

```
var h = new HashSet<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 17519).Select(i => i*17519));
```

Set a brea kpoint, and examine `h` in the debugger. Look at Raw View / Non-public members / m_buckets. Observe that the initial bucket has 17519 elements, while the remaining 17518 all have zeros.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's O(N^2)

Comment: But what about non-amortized, worst case complexity?

Comment: You can force worse than O(n^2) time if you assume a custom time with a poor or malicious `GetHashCode`.  You could have a `GetHashCode` that never returns, for example, and never ever be able to complete the task, or you could have a `GetHashCode` method that takes `O(n^2)` time to compute, thus making the `HashSet` methods...worse than that.

Comment: @Servy My point is that since you have no control over .NET's `GetHashCode` of `Int32`, you cannot force `new HashSet<int>(myIEnumerable)` from the OP into the `O(N^2)` territory. When you have control over `GetHashCode`, you can force `HashSet<T>` to block indefinitely :) `HashSet<long>` is the middle of the road: the worst you can do is `O(N^2)` by supplying a particularly bad sequence for the .NET implementation of `Int64.GetHashCode`.

Comment: For `int`s you still can create collisions of the bucket index. Simply add ints that are a multiple of the `Capacity`. I expect O(n^2) addition performance in such a scenario, but I'm too lazy to figure out the preferred capacities of `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos You are right, you can force `O(N^2)`. I did not realize that it is sufficient to consider only the last size, thinking that you need to try 3, 7, 17, 37, 89, and so on. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

A quick experiment with degenerate hashcode (a constant) shows that it's quadratic.

```
for(int n=0;n<100;n++)
{
    var start=DateTime.UtcNow;
    var s=new HashSet<Dumb>(Enumerable.Range(0,n*10000).Select(_=>new Dumb()));
    Console.Write(n+" ");
    Console.WriteLine((int)((DateTime.UtcNow-start).TotalSeconds*10));
}
```

outputs:

```
0 0
1 8
2 34
3 73
4 131
```

---

Now some claim that you don't get multi collisions of the `HashCode` for ints. While that's technically true, what matters for performance isn't a collision of the HashCode, but a collision of the bucket index. I think `HashSet<T>` uses something like `bucket = (hash&0x7FFFFFFF)%Capacity`. So if you add a sequence of integers that's a multiple of a preferred bucket size, it'll still be very slow.

Comment: If all objects return the same hashcode, than yes, this is O(n*n), because of collisions. But the OP's question was about collection of int's. So I'm wondering how difficult (possible?) would be to choose pair of int's with equal hashcodes.

Comment: I don't think the test you performed is the same as what I described in my question. I am specifically interested in the worst case complexity of passing a collection with a known amount of elements to the `HashSet` constructor, not the complexity of multiple `Add` calls.

Comment: @SergeyS `int` is one of just a handful of types that has *no* collisions.  The number of possible `int` values is not larger than the number of possible `int` values, so the hash code for `int` values is actually *unique* for different values.  (In other words, it's hash code can just return itself.)  Other types such as `byte` and `char` also have less values than `int` and so will never collide.

Comment: Even with it it's possible to cause collisions of the bucket index. It's just more annoying to pull off. | @UghSegment it's the same with the constructor. See updated code.